# Why is the question about SO(4) embedding into SU(3) attracting so many troll answers

Tags: discussion, answers, spam

This question: [Is SO(4) a subgroup of SU(3)?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408648/is-so4-a-subgroup-of-su3) has already attracted 5 rude spam answers (most of which have been deleted by the time I posted this, but if you have enough reputation you can see them). Can anyone fathom a reason why this particular, seemingly random, question is attracting so many rude answers? At any rate, probably it should be locked at this point.

EDIT: As Tim Campion mentioned in the comments, the question is now protected.

Comment: Not sure, but the question is now protected, so hopefully that will be the end of that.

Comment: Given their similarities, they are probably all the same person.

Comment: I'll just mention that this question was in the HNQ list (see the [timeline](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/408648/timeline) and the [revision history](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/408648/revisions).)  Users who are below 10k can check that there were deleted answers [using SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1479912/deleted-answers-to-the-given-post?qid=408648) (but they will be displayed among the results only after the database is updated - which happens once a week).

Comment: I guess that such a question is rather internal to moderation (and is not likely to be fully answered), the troll's rationale not really being of much public interest.

Comment: Since this is the first and only question of the OP and since he does not write under a pseudonym, this could just be the work of some guy who dislikes the OP and wants to annoy him. If this is the case, there will be perhaps a similar reaction to other posts of the OP

Comment: The presumably same troll user has also spammed the question [Is a closed subset of an extremally disconnected set again extremally disconnected](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408839/)